# Is it bad to have "specifications" for a controller/method specified in routing code?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-routing, fluent-interface, api-design

I'm designing an alternative MVC framework for ASP.Net. Part of my goals for the framework is to have as little "magic" as possible. The only bit of reflection I have is for binding things like form, query string, etc to a plain ol' class(with some optional attributes for ignore, conversion, etc). As such, I do absolutely no class/method detection. Everything must be very explicit. I've gone through about 3 iterations of API "shape". The first two achieved my goal of having no magic, but it was very verbose and not easy to read.. and controllers usually had to do the heavy lifting the MVC framework should do.

So, now in this third iteration I'm trying *really* hard to get it right. One slightly *controversial* thing I do differently is the routing code. Because everything is explicit and reflection is discouraged, I can't search for some attribute in the controller to resolve a route. Everything must be specified at the route level. In the first iteration this wasn't done, but it made for extremely cumbersome and verbose controllers...

Right now, I have this fluent API for specifying routes. It has gone a bit beyond what I first imagined though and now functions as a sort of way to specify what a controller's method is capable of and what it should accept.

On to the actual code. The implementation is irrelevant. The only thing you really need to know is that there is a LOT of generic types involved. So, here is a quick sample of some routing:

```
var router=new Router(...);
var blog=router.Controller(() => new BlogController());
blog.Handles("/blog/index").With((ctrl) => ctrl.Index());
blog.Handles("/blog/{id}").With((ctrl,model) => ctrl.View(model["id"])).WhereRouteLike((r) => r["id"].IsInteger()); //model defaults to creating a dictionary from route parameters
blog.Handles("/blog/new").UsingFormModel(() => new BlogPost()).With((ctrl, model) => ctrl.NewPost(model)); //here model would be of type BlogPost. Also, could substitue UsingRouteModel, UsingQueryStringModel, etc
```

There are also some other methods that could be implemented such as `WhereModelIsLike` or some such that does verification on the model. However, does this kind of "specification" belong in the routing layer? What are the limits that should be specified in the routing layer? What should be left to the controller to validate?

Am I making the routing layer worry about too much?

Comment: Convention over Configuration is a *good* thing and nothing that needs to be fixed.

Comment: @DanielHilgarth true... assuming you never mistype a magic string. or actually have a problem you need to debug.. or you don't have the convention memorized... anyway I won't get into my reasons here(I have a blog for that) because they're irrelevant for my question

Comment: So, you have put some thought into it and why you are doing it. That's good and that's actually what I wanted to provoke with my comment.

Comment: @DanielHilgarth yes... I wouldn't say convention is worse than configuration necessarily.. but when using a statically (mostly) typed language, why not let the type system work for you! Other than that, I just prefer **concise** configuration with sane defaults over convention

Comment: But your configuration is everything *but* concise. I am trying to post an answer, but I am not sure how to really reduce the huge amount of necessary code needed with your approach...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think the routing is way too verbose. I wouldn't want to write that kind of code for 20 controllers. Especially, because it is really repetetive.
The problem I see here that even default cases require verbose declarations. Those verbose declarations only should be needed for special cases.
It is expressive and readable, but you might want to consider packaging advanced features up.

Have a look at the following specification. And that's just for a single action in a single controller:

```
blog.Handles("/blog/new")
    .UsingFormModel(() => new BlogPost())
    .With((ctrl, model) => ctrl.NewPost(model))
    .WhereModelIsLike(m => m.Status == PostStatus.New);
```

One way to only slightly reducing the amount of code would be to allow the specification of a root folder:

```
var blog=router.Controller(() => new BlogController(), "/blog");
blog.Handles("index").Wi..
blog.Handles("{id}").Wit..
blog.Handles("new").Usin..
```

Another idea to reduce the code for default cases would be to introduce one interface per default action. The controller needs to implement the interfaces for supported actions:

Something like this maybe:

```
public interface ISupportIndex
{
    void Index();
}

public interface ISupportSingleItem
{
    void View(int id);
}
```

Now, you could provide methods like `blog.HandlesIndex();`, `blog.HandlesSingleItem();`.
Those methods return the same thing as your existing methods, so the result can be further refined.
They could be designed as extension methods that are only available if the controller actually implements the interface. To achieve this, the return type of `router.Controller` would need to be a covariant interface with the controller as generic parameter, i.e. something like this:

```
IControllerRoute<out TController>
```

For example, the extension method `HandlesIndex` would be implemented like this:

```
public static IRouteHandler HandlesIndex(
    this IControllerRoute<ISupportIndex> route)
{
    // note: This makes use of the "root" as suggested above:
    // It only specifies "index", not "/someroot/index".
    return route.Handles("index").With(x => x.Index);
}
```

work on `IControllerRoute<ISupportIndex>`, to be only displayed in cases the controller actually supports it.

The route for the blog controller could look like this:

```
blog.HandlesIndex();
blog.HandlesSingleItem();

// Uses short version for models with default constructor:
blog.HandlesNew<BlogPost>().UsingFormModel();
// The version for models without default constructor could look like this:
//blog.HandlesNew<BlogPost>().UsingFormModel(() => new BlogPost(myDependency));
```

Adding validation rules could be done a little bit more concise, too:

```
blog.HandlesNew<BlogPost>().UsingFormModel()
    .When(m => m.Status == PostStatus.New);
```

If the specification is more complex, it could be packaged in its own class that implements `IModelValidation`. That class is now used:

```
blog.HandlesNew<BlogPost>().UsingFormModel()
    .WithValidator<NewBlogPostValidation>();
```

---

All of my suggestions are just ways to make your current approach easier to handle, so I guess up till now, it doesn't really **answer your actual question**. I do that now:

I like my controllers as clean as possible. Putting validation rules on the route is something that looks very good to me, because the controller action now can assume that it only is called with valid data. I would continue with this approach.

Comment: Heh wow, thanks for the feedback. Maybe I should've posted this to codereview.se

Comment: Another thing, as far as the `IHandlesIndex` and such goes. This could be implemented for common CRUD operations and maybe a few other commons routes. You make some very good points here though that I'll definitely be figuring out how to stuff in without doing a complete rewrite :) (fluent APIs involving generics is hard!)

Comment: @Earlz: Good look figuring that out, generic fluent APIs are indeed hard :)

Answer (score 1):

Yes, IMHO, routing should not contain logic about the model, or even the view.

If you look at light-weight Web frameworks out there now (Nancy etc.), the routing concept does not include things like view link generation. It is entirely about mapping the URI template to the controller. This takes a lot of the "magic" out of the ASP.NET implementation.

https://github.com/NancyFx/Nancy/wiki/Defining-routes

However, the Nancy approach still requires some "framework" code to understand which routes are available.  So, it doesn't fit your requirements exactly.